# Detecting change of SIM card in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to know, how to detect change of SIM card (or) IMSI change  programatically in windows phone 8. In my App, If the user changes the SIM card i need to clear all the details saved in Isolated storage and need to open the APP as a fresh App.i am new to the Windows phone development.

Please someone do the Needful

Thanks..

Comment: Could you explain why you're doing that? I'd find that very frustrating to wipe details just because I swapped a SIM card in/out. And note that non-LTE Verizon Windows Phones do not have a SIM card.

Answer (score -1):

You can't get the phone number from the device, whatever its type was, for a simple reason, that the mobile phone number is not stored on the SIM Card.

SIM Card holds contacts, SMSs, and network information along with an ID to link this SIM card to the User phone number.

so, don't try u will not get it from the SIM, but if it was stored manually in the device anyway else, you can get it then and compare.

to detect if sim changed, you can keep track of the operator. This is not foolproof anyway, if the second sim put is of the same carrier. But still...

```
var CellularNetwork = DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator;
MessageBox.Show(CellularNetwork);
```

Comment: IMSI number is a unique number to identify GSM subscriber, it is not a phone number. IMSI number is embedded in the SIM Card.